# Can I select 2nd element of a 2 dimensional array by value of the first element in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have a JSON response like this:

```
 var errorLog = "[[\"comp\",\"Please add company name!\"],
                 [\"zip\",\"Please add zip code!\"],
                  ...
```

Which I'm deserializing like this:

```
 var log = jQuery.parseJSON(errorLog);
```

Now I can access elements like this:

```
 log[1][1] > "Please add company name"
```

**Question**:
If I have the first value **comp**, is there a way to directly get the 2nd value by doing:

```
 log[comp][1]
```

without looping through the whole array.

Thanks for help!

Comment: I'm getting undefined. I tried with toLowerCase() and without

Comment: Can you change the array to an object?

Comment: @SLaks: no, this is bound into to many things client and server-side

Comment: Does `comp` hold the value of the first-dimension array or the index within that array?

Comment: You would have to search for comp and then get the second value. Currently you are using it as an index and so should be an int. you could use a for loop until you found comp and then access the second element from there

Comment: @GreenGiant - so the only way is looping and comparing values?

Comment: It is the only way i can think of. Loops are pretty simple and you can  exit the loop when you find the element. it might be best to make a function for this where you send what you are looking for adn the reference to the array and either return the index or just print the message right away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two was to do this, but neither avoids a loop. The first is to loop through the array each time you access the items:

```
var val = '';
for (var i = 0; i < errorLog.length; i++) {
    if (errorLog[i][0] === "comp") {
        val = errorLog[i][1];
        break;
    }
}
```

The other would be to work your array into an object and access it with object notation.

```
var errors = {};
for (var i = 0; i < errorLog.length; i++) {
    errors[errorLog[i][0]] = errorLog[i][1];
}
```

You could then access the relevant value with `errors.comp`.

If you're only looking once, the first option is probably better. If you may look more than once, it's probably best to use the second system since (a) you only need to do the loop once, which is more efficient, (b) you don't repeat yourself with the looping code, (c) it's immediately obvious what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

No. Unless the 'value' of the first array (maybe I should say, the first dimension, or the first row), is also it's **key**. That is, unless it is something like this:

```
log = {
    'comp': 'Please add a company name'
                   .
                   .
                   .
}
```

Now, `log['comp']` or `log.comp` is legal.

Comment: hm. so my [value1, value2] is not very helpful :-( Thanks for the info

Comment: Not the way you want. Anyways, looping is always available right? But, you might be worried about performance, mightn't you?

Comment: @frequent In Javascript, you should use objects to find elements by value, otherwise, you should keep track of indicies (or "keys") to quickly navigate arrays.

Comment: you can always break the loop so you don't have to go throught the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

No matter what you are going to loop through the array somehow even it is obscured for you a bit by tools like jQuery.

You could create an object from the array as has been suggested like this:

```
var objLookup = function(arr, search) {
    var o = {}, i, l, first, second;

    for (i=0, l=arr.length; i<l; i++) {
        first = arr[i][0]; // These variables are for convenience and readability.
        second = arr[i][1]; // The function could be rewritten without them.

        o[first] = second;
    }

    return o[search];
}
```

But the faster solution would be to just loop through the array and return the value as soon as it is found:

```
var indexLookup = function(arr, search){
   var index = -1, i, l;

    for (i = 0, l = arr.length; i<l; i++) {
        if (arr[i][0] === search) return arr[i][1];
    }

    return undefined;
}
```

You could then just use these functions like this in your code so that you don't have to have the looping in the middle of all your code:

```
var log = [
    ["comp","Please add company name!"],
    ["zip","Please add zip code!"]
];

objLookup(log, "zip"); // Please add zip code!
indexLookup(log, "comp"); // Please add company name!
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pseudosavant/MAm4n/) that shows these in use.

Comment: also thanks, I went with lonesomeday's proposal. +1 for you, too!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at jQuery's `grep` or `inArray` method?

See this discussion

[Are there any jquery features to query multi-dimensional arrays in a similar fashion to the DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191199/are-there-any-jquery-features-to-query-multi-dimensional-arrays-in-a-similar-fas)

Comment: That's a question and a link, not an answer :)